# Integral of Brownian motion times deterministic function

Tags: integration, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I'm new to stochastic calculus, and I'm trying to evaluate: $$ \int_{0}^{1} W(r) f(r) dr, $$ and $$ \int_{0}^{t} W(r) f(r) dr, $$  where $f(t)$ is a deterministic square-integrable function and $W(t)$ is the standard brownian motion, with respect to time. For instance, we can consider a case where:

$$ \int_{0}^{1} W(r) \cos (2\pi r) dr $$ or for instance:

$$ \int_{0}^{1} W(r) e^{-r} dr $$

How could I use properties of the standard brownian motion to evaluate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ has an anti-derivative, say $F$, you can perform integration by parts:
$$Z_t = \int_0^t W(r) f(r) dr = W(t) F(t) - \int_0^t F(s) dW_s = \int_0^t (F(t) - F(s)) dW_s$$

Since the Itô integral of a deterministic function is a Gaussian process, you can now fully identify $Z_t$ by computing its mean and covariance.

Comment: Thanks!! :) So for instance in the case of $f(t) = e^{-t}$, I'd have that $\int_{0}^{t} (e^{-s} - e^{-t})dW(s)$ is a gaussian white noise? And that's why I'd just have to figure its mean and covariance to identify it?

Comment: It would be a Gaussian process, but not a white noise. The need to find the mean and variance of the process arises from the fact that the distribution of a Gaussian process is determined by its mean and covariance.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey Jose, you seem to know a lot of stochastic calculus. Any tips on good reads on that subject? So far I'm reading Steele's book :)

Comment: I'm a big fan of Kuo's book for a gentle introduction. Steele's book is great too, especially if you are interested in finance. For a more thorough treatment, Diffusions, Markov Processes, and Martingales is a good text. You can also find really good sets of lecture notes on stochastic calculus everywhere in the web, just Google [Uni name] + "stochastic calculus notes".